# My data population no longer works after using Django's User model. Why?

Tags: python, django, django-models

This code works perfectly, which is a User model with one to many relationship with UserRating model.

View:

```
def index(request):
    user_list = User.objects.order_by('-userrating')[:5]
    city_list = City.objects.order_by('-name')[:5]

    context_dict = {"users": user_list, "cities" : city_list}

    return render(request, "index.html", context_dict)
```

Models:

```
# this is model for user
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    profilepic = models.ImageField(null=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    secondname = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Uncomment if you don't want the slug to change every time the name changes
        # if self.id is None:
        # self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        self.slug = slugify(self.username)
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

    @property
    def avg_rating(self):
        return self.userrating_set.all().aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg']


# this is the model for user ratings - one to many relationship with User
class UserRating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    for_username = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=5)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.rating)
```

However, it breaks once I use Django's built in User model as below (User model with one to one relationship with a UserProfile model and a one to many relationship with UserRating)

```
# this is model for user
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    profilepic = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.user.username)
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

    @property
    def avg_rating(User):
        return self.userrating_set.all().aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg']


# this is the model for user ratings - one to many relationship with User
class UserRating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    for_username = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=5)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.rating)
```

it generates this error when adding a user profile via admin page:

```
super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Answer (score 1):

You must call the actual superclass in your `super` call; it is UserProfile, not User.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.user.username)
    super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```